# while sending mail using gmail api html part is also going along with content instead of content

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

Here is the piece of code I wrote in node js:

```
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    let str = [
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message,
    ].join('');
    return str;
}

let raw = makeBody("dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", "dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", 
"Test mail", "Everything is fine");
const userId = 'me'; // Please modify this for your situation.
let option = {
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/" + userId + "/messages/send",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.query.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822',
    },
    body: raw,
};
```

When I am sending mail with html content as I am using some editor in front-end part. In the mail also html content is going. How to stop it. I have tried using text/html in content-type but it throws error.

Mail going as:

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Hi,</strong></em></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Would like to know more about deal. Let's meet.</strong></em></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Thanks,</strong></em></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><em><strong>Samresh</strong></em></p>
```

Comment: Found the solution for this problem